# get html element from Angular directive

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to pass a parameter to my Angular directive. In the HTML I'm  seting `current_user` from Ruby on Rails like this:

```
<user_menu current_user="#{current_user_email}"></user_menu>
```

And in the directive (`user_menu.js`) I try to get it:

```
angular.module('mgApp.directives').directive('userMenu', function(){
return {
restrict: 'E',
templateUrl: 'user_menu/user_menu.html',
scope: {
    current_user: '='
},
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    alert("current_user:" + scope.current_user)
}
```

But it's not working. `current_user` is undefined.
Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
<user_menu current_user="current_user_email"></user_menu>.
```

but **current_user_email** must be in the scope of your controller

Comment: thanks @hic1086, but #{current_user_email} is a rails attribute not a text. It's going to have the value of the user email

Comment: You could not attribute it to a variable of your controller scope?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `<user_menu current_user="#{{current_user_email}}"></user_menu>`

Or, try it without the curly braces?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: Have you tried <user_menu current_user="#{{current_user_email}}"></user_menu>

Or, try it without the curly braces?